# My code is not displaying a message I programmed it to show

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

It is a flask app that I am currently working on.
My code is supposed to validate user input. It is supposed to display a message whenever a user tries to create an account with an already existing email/username in the database. The validation part of the code is working as it does not redirect the user to the login page nor does it return an actual error in the browser, which is why I am ASSUMING that the validation part of the code is working. It is just that it is not displaying the message I wrote in the ValidationError() portion of the code.

Here is the forms.py file:

```
import flask_wtf
import wtforms
import wtforms.validators
from yff.models import User


class RegistrationForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):

    username = wtforms.StringField('Username',
                            validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(), wtforms.validators.Length(min=3, max=20)])
    email = wtforms.StringField('Email', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(),
                                            wtforms.validators.Email()])
    password = wtforms.PasswordField('Password', validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired()])
    confirmPassword = wtforms.PasswordField('Confirm Password', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(), wtforms.validators.EqualTo('password')])
    remember = wtforms.BooleanField('Remember me')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Create Account')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()

        if user:
            raise wtforms.validators.ValidationError(message='That username is taken. Please choose a different one.')
    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()

        if user:
            raise wtforms.validators.ValidationError(message='That email is taken. Please choose a different one.')


class LoginForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    email = wtforms.StringField('Email', 
                        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired(),
                                            wtforms.validators.Email()])
    password = wtforms.PasswordField('Password', validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired()])
    remember = wtforms.BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('Login')
```

Here is the models.py file:

```
from yff import db, login_manager
from flask_login import UserMixin

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    profile_pic = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=False, default="default.jpg")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.username}, {self.email}'
```

Here is the createacc.html template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <div id="username-field">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <span>{{ message }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ form.username(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="email-field">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <span>{{ message }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {{ form.email(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="password-field">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-label") }}
                        {% if form.password.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                                <span>{{ message }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {{ form.password(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="confirm-pass-field">
                    {{ form.confirmPassword.label(class="form-label") }}
                        {% if form.confirmPassword.errors %}
                            {% for error in form.confirmPassword.errors %}
                                <span>{{ message }}</span>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    {{ form.confirmPassword(class='form-el') }}
                </div>
                <div id="submit-field">
                    {{ form.submit(class='submit-btn') }}
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="check">
                <small id="al-account">
                    Already have an account? Head to our <a id="check-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login page</a>
                </small>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for the route that all of the previous code runs on:

```
@app.route("/create-account", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def createacc():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    isValid = form.validate_on_submit()
    if isValid:
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"Your account has been created succcessfully. You can now log in.")
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('createacc.html', title="Register", form=form)
```

The input fields display the messages for the DataRequired() validator, but not for the custom validators that I made. Again, I do not get any errors, it is just that the message in the ValidationError() is not displayed. I have shared all the code where I suspect the reason for this not working as I want it to exists.

Comment: I haven't @WinmariManzano. Shouldn't the {{form.hidden_tag()}} be enough for that?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are looping through the error messages with the variable `error` (`{% for error in form.<field>.errors %}`). But you then try to show a variable called `message` (`<span>{{ message }}</span>`). I think you actually wanted `<span>{{ error}}</span>`.

Comment: @PatrickYoder Oh boy, I can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Better be careful next time. Thank you so much, Patrick! It works!!